# Laravel, Anonymous Global scopes with joins

Tags: php, laravel, scope

Using Anonymous Global Scopes. I'm getting a error.
here is my code,

```
protected static function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    $userId = 1;
    static::addGlobalScope('users', function (Builder $builder) use ($userId) {
     $builder->join("accounts_profiles_biz", 'users.id', '=', 'accounts_profiles_biz.user_id')->where('users.user_id', $userId);
    });
}
```

here is error

```
Exception Code: "SQLSTATE[42702]: Ambiguous column: 7 ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous LINE 1: ...s"."id" = "accounts_profiles_biz"."user_id" where "id" = $1 ... ^ (SQL: select * from "users" inner join "accounts_profiles_biz" on "users"."id" = "accounts_profiles_biz"."user_id" where "id" = 1 and "users"."deleted_at" is null and "users"."user_id" = 1 limit 1)"
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: please include the error message, one more thing that global scopes are added to every query. I think you should go with local scope.

Comment: this error is for insertion opertion, not for scoping or querying, it must be in another part of your code

Comment: @OMR 
here is error

Exception Code: "SQLSTATE[42702]: Ambiguous column: 7 ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous LINE 1: ...s"."id" = "accounts_profiles_biz"."user_id" where "id" = $1 ... ^ (SQL: select * from "users" inner join "accounts_profiles_biz" on "users"."id" = "accounts_profiles_biz"."user_id" where "id" = 1 and "users"."deleted_at" is null and "users"."user_id" = 1 limit 1)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the problem in this line:

```
  $builder->join("accounts_profiles_biz", 'users.id', '=', 
'accounts_profiles_biz.user_id')->where('users.user_id', $userId);
```

users.user_id column is not existed as I think ..

it should be:

```
  $builder->join("accounts_profiles_biz", 'users.id', '=', 'accounts_profiles_biz.user_id')
```

**`->where('users.id', $userId);`**

Comment: no , getting same error, 


Exception Code: "SQLSTATE[42702]: Ambiguous column: 7 ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous LINE 1: ...s"."id" = "accounts_profiles_biz"."user_id" where "id" = $1 ... ^ (SQL: select * from "users" inner join "accounts_profiles_biz" on "users"."id" = "accounts_profiles_biz"."user_id" where "id" = 1 and "users"."deleted_at" is null limit 1)"

Comment: can you share the code that uses this scope? I mean the query that use it?

Comment: I'm using Anonymous Global.

protected static function boot(){
    parent::boot();
    $userId = 1;
    static::addGlobalScope('users', function (Builder $builder) use ($userId) {
     $builder->join("accounts_profiles_biz", 'users.id', '=', 'accounts_profiles_biz.user_id')->where('users.user_id', $userId);
    });
}

Comment: do you have a column called user_id in table users?

Comment: no , user_id is a colum in that table "accounts_profiles_biz"

Comment: so why you use : ->where('users.user_id', $userId)

Comment: after changing.

$builder->join("accounts_profiles_biz", 'users.id', '=', 'accounts_profiles_biz.user_id')->where('users.id', $userId);

Exception Code: "SQLSTATE[42702]: Ambiguous column: 7 ERROR: column reference "id" is ambiguous LINE 1: ...s"."id" = "accounts_profiles_biz"."user_id" where "id" = $1 ... ^ (SQL: select * from "users" inner join "accounts_profiles_biz" on "users"."id" = "accounts_profiles_biz"."user_id" where "id" = 1 and "users"."deleted_at" is null and "users"."id" = 1 limit 1)"

Comment: can you share some article or something which could help in global scope with inner join.

Comment: global scope take a query builder as a parameter, just like many clouser in Laravel, you can use  that query builder to make join, whereHas, with, selectSub, and any thing else